# JS получение названия класса

Tags: javascript

Просто копирую к себе в код какой-нибудь пример получения названия класса:

```
class Class1 {
}
const c1 = new Class1();
console.log(c1.constructor.name);
console.log(c1.constructor.name === 'Class1');
```

Вместо

```
Class1
true
```

Я вижу

```
e
false
```

Что это значит?

Comment: А где вы запускаете этот код?

Comment: @DreamChild, в Android приложении с помощью React Native

Comment: похоже на результат минификации

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, в React Native невозможно получить имя класса таким образом. Сурс: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41216782/how-do-i-get-string-name-of-react-native-component-class#comment72404099_41218686